# turning a null string into a white space in a morse code reader

Tags: java

I am trying to write a morse code translator for a challenge. at the moment I have got as far as translating the morse code into a String array and am passing it through a `for` loop to build the message.

I am currently getting `HEYnullnullJUDE` and am working out how to detect 2 spaces which in morse code will act as a word space. however when I use an `if` statement to detect `.isEmpty` or `.isBlank` or `.length() == 0` the `for` loop exits and I get a return of:

```
9
this is split  = [...., ., -.--, , , .---, ..-, -.., .]
H
H
E
HE
Y
HEY
```

for some reason once it hits `Null`, instead of executing the `nullCount` it just exits and return `HEY` and I'm not sure.

what is the best way of turning `HEYnullnullJUDE` which i am getting now into `HEY JUDE` and detecting the double space in the morse code?

this is taken from this codewars challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/54b724efac3d5402db00065e/train/java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MorseCodeDecoder {
    public static String decode(String morseCode) {
        
       String[] split = morseCode.trim().split(" ");
        int length = split.length;
        System.out.println(length);
        System.out.println("this is split  = " + Arrays.toString(split));

        MorseCode morseCoder = new MorseCode();
        
        String message = "";

        for (int i =0; i < length; i++){
          int nullCount = 0;
            

// this is where the code exits for some reason

            if(morseCoder.get(split[i]) == null{
              nullCount++;
              System.out.println(nullCount);
              if (nullCount == 2){
                nullCount =0;
                message = message + " ";
              }
            }
// if this is "if"statment is removed i get HEYnullnullJUDE

          System.out.println (morseCoder.get(split[i]));
        message = message + morseCoder.get(split[i]);
            System.out.println(message);
              
        }
      return message;
      
    }
}

samble test
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class MorseCodeDecoderTest {
    @Test
    public void testExampleFromDescription() {
      assertThat(MorseCodeDecoder.decode(".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."), is("HEY JUDE"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better if you just use ``split("\\s+")`` which will split on one or more spaces without leaving null elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is `".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."`.

Since you call `trim()`, there will be no leading or trailing spaces seen by `split()`.

To see the 3 spaces as a single space in the result of the `split()`, you basically don't want to split on the middle of the 3 spaces. Said another way, you only want to split on a space that follows a non-space or a space that is followed by a non-space.

```
        Split on these
    ↓ ↓    ↓ ↓    ↓   ↓   ↓
.... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .
            ↑
      Don't split on this
```

If you use `split("(?<=[^ ]) | (?=[^ ])")`, then the result becomes:

```java
{ "....", ".", "-.--", " ", ".---", "..-", "-..", "." }
```

Here the space in the morse code truly becomes a string with a single space.

I'll leave the rest to you, e.g. how to make `morseCoder.get(" ")` return a `" "` (or `' '`, whatever the type may be).

---

**UPDATE**

From comment:

> MorseCode.get does not include " " space detection

`morseCoder.get(" ")` return a `" "` was just an **example** of how it could be solved. Alternatively, simply check if a space is encountered, *before* calling `morseCoder.get(...)`, e.g.

```java
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuider();
for (String symbol : split) {
    if (symbol.equals(" ")) {
        buf.append(' ');
    } else {
        String str = morseCoder.get(split[i]);
        buf.append(str == null ? "�" : str);
    }
}
String message = buf.toString();
```

Comment: unfortunatly the MorseCode.get does not include " " space detection. so i need to find a way to detect the tripple space and then add the space in. this is why i was trying to use null (which i now know is wrong) to count up and if it hit a certain number a space would be inserted. but since i cant detect null i need to find another way the capture/detect the 3 spaces.
i tried your  ' split("(?<=[^ ]) | (?=[^ ])") ' but it return HEYnullJUDE , better but not quite what i need. thank you anyway, ill keep at it.

Comment: @dirge0matic Easy to fix, simply **check** if `split[i].equals(" ")` *before* trying to call `morseCoder.get(...)`.

Comment: thanks, so simple i was not seeing the forrest for the trees. i was overthinking the last bit because i saw null again not realissing the space was there. wish i understood how the ' split("(?<=[^ ]) | (?=[^ ])") ' worked as i understand the basics but am still confused to how the arguments (?<=[^ ]) | (?=[^ ]) work but even the split() documentation hurts my head at this stage of my learning.